# 2004 ford taurus - screeching sound when attempting to start the car

Tags: ford, starting, ignition, starter, cold-start

To start, I know nothing about cars aside from how to drive them. I have a pre owned 2004 ford taurus with 60000 miles. Recently, it has been making a screeching noise when I turn the key to start the car, and fails to start. The check engine light has never been on for as long as I have owned it and it passed PA state inspection perfectly fine two months ago I took the car to a reputable mechanic who replaced the starter. The car still does the funky screeching sound. It is completely random about when it does it as well, and normally, will start after I try the ignition again. Today however, I tried 6 times to start it, and only heard the screehing noise. In addition, my car always jolts or surges when i try to accelerate, right around 40mph and 60mph. My mechanicaachanged the fuel filter (or something like that) and said it would be better - it isnt. I am a college student and commute, so I NEED a functioning car and do not have a lot of money to spend on diagnosing/fixing it with a ford dealer. What could be wrong with my car?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Screeching noise when attempting to start car](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/18496/screeching-noise-when-attempting-to-start-car)

Comment: @JoshCaswell - While the title is basically the same, I don't think this is the same issue.

Comment: To the OP - Can you describe the "funky screeching sound" a little better? It only happens randomly? I take it when the car does start, there's no check engine light? Also, you need a separate question, as the acceleration issue is a completely different issue. I have an idea what you may be experiencing with the startup, but I need some more description about what's going on before I will write an answer as such.

Answer (score 1):

The starter replacement was a likely good guess. Starters are one part that can be purchased "rebuilt" that is, used. If it was rebuilt, this starter may have the same problem as your original. Did the mechanic offer a warranty? If that rebuilt starter is flawed, the mechanic may only have a short time to return it to his supplier for exchange, so you need to have the talk with him now. Consider asking the mechanic about having the starter replaced with a guaranteed new part starter by the manufacturer. This part will likely cost you a lot more. Call a dealership yourself and learn the price, for reference.